# The meaning of 'someone is many things'

Tags: reading-comprehension

The following sentence is from [the article of the Wall Street Jounral](https://www.wsj.com/articles/the-midterm-power-of-parents-smiley-murray-washington-gop-education-schools-closures-pandemic-teachers-unions-weingarten-11662673129?st=8emtjagpv5khggc&reflink=desktopwebshare_permalink).

> American Federation of Teachers President Randi Weingarten is *many things*, though some Republicans hope that this midterm she’s the gift that keeps on giving.

That is the first sentence in the article. There is no preceding context.

I know 'someone is many things' means 'someone has many aspects or characteristics'. And I understand the latter clause as that some Republicans think she does wrong things and it would be helpful for the Republican Party in this midterm election. But within these understandings, the 'though' doesn't make sense because those clauses don't seem to have any relations in context. Maybe I misunderstand much.

What does the whole sentence mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right that "someone is many things" means "someone has many aspects or characteristics". What's missing is the nuance that it's almost always negative, as in:

> Mark may be many things, but he's not a liar.

So in the context of this article, it means "*Randi Weingarten is bad in many ways...*". This contrasts with "*she’s the gift that keeps on giving*", so "though" makes sense.